# "Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError " error from trying to use api from within React Cordova iOS, but works fine in Android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, google-maps, cordova

I have in my index.html for my WebApp and Cordova App:

And the code works perfectly to load the google api, in my webapp, and Cordova for iOS and Android apps.

For the webapp I loaded the various URLs that I wanted to authorize:

```
http://wevote.us/*
https://wevote.us/* 
http://localhost:3000/* 
https://localhost:3000/*
```

All worked perfectly for the webapp.

Then I ran the same code in Android (within Cordova).  A console error said to add "**file_url**//android_asset/www/index.html#/ballot" on the Google Cloud Console, which I did, and 5 minutes later my hybrid Android app was working perfectly.

```
__file_url__//android_asset/www/index.html#/ballot
```

But with iOS, the similar console error says

```
2018-05-23 13:59:22.344204-0700 WeVoteCordova[52841:2772856] ERROR: Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error Your site URL to be authorized: __file_url__//Users/stevepodell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D476226046...99AEE3DC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7A844..10D/WeVoteCordova.app/www/index.html#/ballot
```

Clearly any URL that contains paths on my Mac is not going to work, but as an experiment, I simply added that suggested url (knowing it would only work for one build, on one simulator) and the Google Cloud Server API key page crashed on save, and did not retain the data.

Has anyone gotten this to work on iOS?

There is a google bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828931 but it is closed, and it looks like it is not being seen.

Updated May 24, 2018:

There now is an open google bug [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80230742](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828931)